# How to startActivity() in a subclass of Dialog?

Tags: android

I have one subclass which extends `Dialog` class, it seems I can not use
`startActivity()` function to start a new Activity in this subclass which extends `Dialog` class, how to resolve it?

How to start a new Activity in a Dialog subclass? (In my customized dialog subclass, I have
one button, when pressed, I would like to have a new Activity start).

Answer (score 4):

[`startActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) is a method of `Context`.

You can retrieve the `Context` of your `Dialog` by calling [`Dialog.getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#getContext%28%29).

Comment: No, this does not help. startActivity() can only be called inside a class which extends Activity, my class extends Dialog, and I want to startActivity in side this, subclass of Dialog class...

Comment: `startActivity` is a public method - what happens when you try to invoke it from `Dialog`? (when you call `getContext().startActivity`?)

Answer (score 2):

Can I see where you are invoking the dialog?

Im guessing, in some sort of activity, you have this dialog show, and based on the selection, you launch a new activity.

If you were using nested classes you could just do this by using startActivity(currentClassName.this,targetClass.class), but since you have your own class extending dialog, I would try including the context in the constructor for the dialog class and launch the new activity based on that, that way, the activity can be launched from your dialog class, using its "parent" activity context.

I havent tried this, so it might not work, but give it a shot.

So from the activity that invokes the dialog, it would be someting like

```
MyDialog d = new MyDialog(currentClassName.this);
```

From inside your MyDialogClass:

```
public class MyDialog{
   private Context c;

   public MyDialog(Context c){
      this.c=c;
   }

   public startActivityFromDialog(){
      startActivity(c,something.class);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still call `startActivity` on a non activity context, but you have to launch it into a new task, by adding the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag.

This does have some ramifications though, so I'd rather try to get my hands on an `Activity` within that dialog, for example by launching the dialog using an actual activity, and not `getApplicationContext()` or somesuch.

Otherwise, no dice.

For more about tasks, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask